# Should you return HTML from a web service?

Tags: web-services, soa

I have a situation where two components are being designed that have some similar presentation requirements, but have been built using different technology stacks (one is java and the other is .net). For one feature, the developers are propsing using a web service that returns HTML so that both components can re-use the same display logic. I have been told that it is a bad practice to use a web service in this fashion, and that a web service should focus only on **data**.

In terms of web-service or SOA best practrices, should you return HTML from a web service?

Answer (score 0):

If it's actually a web service (i.e. meant to be called by scripts), HTML is a bad idea, as you'll have a difficult time handling error situations.

A well-designed XML or JSON answer is probably the way to go these days.